# Embed Flash in Facebook status update

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do you create a Facebook status update that embeds Flash like this http://www.facebook.com/adidasoriginals/posts/173233146043948

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you post

```
http://www.adidas.com/campaigns/holidaycountdown/content/default.aspx?countryCode=us&dayID=18&productID=G17079&marketID=eu&cm_mmc=Facebook-_-Originals-_-Advent-_-G17079
```

to your wall, it works too. Look at this

```
        <meta name="video_width" content="460" />
        <meta name="video_height" content="460" />
        <meta name="video_type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
        <link rel="image_src" href="http://www.adidas.com/campaigns/holidaycountdown/content/assets/images/fb_wall_thumbs/130x130_day18.jpg?fbrefresh=2" /> 
        <link rel="video_src" href="http://www.adidas.com/campaigns/holidaycountdown/content/assets/swf/main.swf?domain=http://www.adidas.com/&configXMLURL=http://www.adidas.com/campaigns/holidaycountdown/content/assets/xml/config.xml&day=18&fbrefresh=2"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. Works if you post this as well http://www.adidas.com/holidaycountdown/18/G17079/eu/

Comment: I think it might have something to do with meta data you supply using og:video http://ogp.me/#video